# append last 5 lines of all CSV files in a directory to 1 Dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, csv, concatenation

I need to create a dataframe to push to database containing the last 5 lines (all columns) of all CSV files in directory.

So far here is what I have, but it is not adding Data and just says `Empty DataFrame`

```
#blank Dataframe
cols = ['ticker', 'date', 'open', 'high', 'low', 'close', 'volume', 'time']
insert_list = pd.DataFrame(columns = cols)

#select csvs to merge
listdrs = os.listdir(string)
listdrs_path = [ string + x for x in listdrs]
#loop through csv's
for file_path in listdrs_path:
    data = pd.read_csv(file_path, index_col=0)
    insert_list.append(data.tail(5))
    
#save list as new csv
insert_list.to_csv('compressed_update.csv')
```

Comment: `append()` is not an inplace operation you should store the result back in `insert_list`

Comment: Worked like a charm! Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Code updated based on resources shared in the comments:

```
for file_path in listdrs_path:
    data = pd.read_csv(file_path, index_col=0).tail(5)
    insert_list = insert_list.append(data)
```